# WinRT GUI within a desktop application

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, mahapps.metro

We have a C++ desktop application using an old MFC GUI; now we want to have a more modern touch GUI. We would like to use the Windows Metro App style.
Because we use some sdk that link shared mfc libraries, we think that we cannot write a WinRT application using these components (or we are wrong?).

Is it possible to use WinRT GUI api within a desktop application (with pure C++ without anything of the .net world, like [WRL/C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438466.aspx))?
 We see some example i.e. [using accelerometer WinRT api](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2013/10/02/using-windows-8-winrt-apis-in-net-desktop-applications.aspx), but not GUI components.

Comment: It's a perfect valid qustion. Why was this closed. This closing fascism really starts to suck.

THe answer is:  No - you can't mix WinRT GUI and normal Win32 GUI. And i don't think that WinRT is good enough at the moment to port it. The mentioned reason was that Win32 is unimproveable because of all this old Win32 windows message stuff that nobody wants to break, so they created a new level on top of it. But as usual, MS stopped half way on this mission, leaving us with something much less useable then Cocoa.

Comment: Two older, Sep 2012, blog posts about Accessing WinRT from Desktop apps. Part 1 http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/09/13/accessing-winrt-from-desktop-apps-part-1/ and Part 2 http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/09/24/accessing-winrt-from-desktop-apps-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that C++/CX is pure native stuff. There is no .NET dependencies etc. It is just a language extension to simplify COM interop (i'm sure you know that WinRT is COM-based API) but if you don't like C++/CX, consider WRL for low-level interop.

The language extensions of C++/CX save time, but you don’t have to use them. You can get lower-level access to cross-language interop from standard C++ if you use the Windows Runtime C++ Template Library (WRL). WRL uses conventions that will be familiar to COM programmers.

WRL is a compiler-agnostic way to create and consume Windows Runtime APIs. You can use the WRL instead of the C++/CX syntax. It enables you to optimize your code for performance or for specific scenarios. It also supports app development methodologies that don't use exceptions.

Comment: "For authoring and consuming Windows Runtime APIs using C++, there is C++/WinRT. This is Microsoft's recommended replacement for the Windows Runtime C++ Template Library (WRL) and C++/CX." [Windows Dev Center - C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/index)